# Querying inner objects by field name in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading the documentation on this site: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_how_inner_objects_are_indexed

I'm interested in this paragraph:

Inner fields can be referred to by name (for example, first). To distinguish between two fields that have the same name, we can use the full path (for example, user.name.first) or even the type name plus the path (tweet.user.name.first).
so if I have the example from the linked docu site:

```
{
  "gb": {
    "tweet": { 
      "properties": {
        "tweet":            { "type": "string" },
        "user": { 
          "type":             "object",
          "properties": {
            "id":           { "type": "string" },
            "gender":       { "type": "string" },
            "age":          { "type": "long"   },
            "name":   { 
              "type":         "object",
              "properties": {
                "full":     { "type": "string" },
                "first":    { "type": "string" },
                "last":     { "type": "string" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the docu I should be able to search with condition *last: whatever*, but it does not work. I always have to use the full path *user.last: whatever*. Is the documentation false or my understanding of it? Note that last occurs only in the inner object, so in theory full path should not be necessary to reference it.

edit:

query that works:

```
get /my_index/_search?q=user.name.last:test
```

query that does not work but should according to documentation:

```
get /my_index/_search?q=last:test
```

Comment: What query are you using?

Comment: I don't agree that the documentation says your query will work. It's doubly nested but you're querying the grandfather.

Comment: but why would it then explain how to distinguish between two fields with the same name?